# Perl to convert data into JSON format

Tags: json, perl

I have a problem, converting my data into json, and I don't know why.

Here is some Code that works:

```
#constructor
sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $Titel = shift;
  my $Text = shift;
  my $Time = localtime;
  my $self = {};

  $self->{text} = $Text;
  $self->{create} = $Time;
  $self->{edit} = $Time;

  my $json = JSON::XS->new();

  open WF, '>> $file' || die "Error : $!";
  print WF $json->encode($self)."\n";
  close WF;

  bless $self, $class;
}
```

I create an 'object' and save the data in a textfile (via JSON), too.

I have problems, if I try to edit some data:

```
sub edit {
my $self = shift;
my $Text = shift;
my $ID = shift;
my $Time = localtime;
my $json = JSON::XS->new();
$json->allow_blessed(1);

$self->{text} = $Text; #edit text
$self->{edit} = $Time; # edit date

open INPUT, '< $file' || die "Error : $!";
my @data = <INPUT>;
close(INPUT);

open WF, '> $file' || die "Error : $!";

for (my $Count=0; $Count<=$#data; $Count++){
    chomp($data[$Count]);

    if($Count == $ID){#if line of data found, who is going to be edited
        print WF $json->encode($self)."\n";
    }else{
        print WF $data[$Count]."\n";
    }
}

close WF;
}
```

What I try to do is to edit just one line in the textfile.. (if you have a better idea, please show me :D)

I see no difference between my procedure in the code shown first and that one....

it just writes "null" back in the textfile...

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to use double quotes around your second argument's to `open`, since the single quotes you have now will not interpolate the `$file` variable.  Better yet is to use the 3 argument form `open INPUT, '<', $file`

Comment: My problem is, that it writes "null" back in line 
-->print WF $json->encode($self)."\n";<--

i can open the file and so on (i edited the code..wrong. sorry :D there is a path in my original code and not '$file'. didn't know that)

Comment: Is "sub edit" called as a method?  ie "$thing->edit ()"?

Comment: yes. i debugged it and $self is the right one when i call the edit method. i can edit the values in my programm, too. only the writeback in the textfile won't work (JUST in the lower code snippet! in the upper one it works perfectly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no JSON expert, but the `encode` method is having trouble with a blessed reference. Using an unblessed reference seems like a valid workaround:

```
if($Count == $ID){#if line of data found, who is going to be edited
    print WF $json->encode( {%$self} )."\n";
...
```

Comment: Thats why i enabled it -->$json->allow_blessed(1);<-- your code won't work, anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: hmm but your right... there were problems cause of the blessed reference... i saved the data in a tmp scalar and encoded that one... now it works. thanks :))

Comment: Looking at the [`JSON`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON) docs, `JSON::allow_blessed` will suppress exceptions when a blessed object is passed to `encode`. But encoding the blessed object requires you to (1) also call `$json->convert_blessed(1)` and (2) implement a `TO_JSON` object method that returns the value to encode. This value must also be an unblessed reference.

Answer (score 1):

I second the notion (as you have already found) that the problem is the blessed reference, however I offer you another solution (the is Perl after all: TIMTOWTDI). The [Acme::Damn](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Acme%3a%3aDamn) module allows you to unbless (i.e. damn) an object. Therefore you should be able to:

```
print WF $json->encode(damn($self))."\n";
```

Also I felt I had to share, since the method is so cleverly named.

Answer (score -1):

Following the last mob's suggestion, here is simple example how to serialize blessed references.

```
package Node;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    bless { @_ }, $class;
}

sub TO_JSON {
    my $self = shift;
    return { class => 'Node', data => { %$self } };
}

package main;

use JSON;

my $node_hash = {
    a => [ 'text1', 'text2' ],
    b => [ 'what',  'is', 'this' ],
    c => [ Node->new(some => 'data') ],
};

print to_json($node_hash, { convert_blessed => 1 });
```

However you need to pay attention in decoding. It is possible to use [filter_json_single_key_object](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON#filter_json_single_key_object) to implement full round-trip.